# Calling function in html and setting it to a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am tring to call a function `getWidth(heading)` from my HTML page and set it to a variable `width` as below:

HTML page:

```
div> style="white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; width:{{getWidth(heading)}}px; overflow: hidden; max-height:48px;" data-ng-bind="$eval('row.' + heading.key) | formatter:heading.format" title="{{$eval('row.' + heading.key) | formatter:heading.format}}">
```

function :

```
$scope.getWidth = function(heading){
  return  document.getElementById($scope.tableId).scrollWidth*heading.width/100 - 24;
            };
```

The way I have added the function with curly braces..Chrome is calculating the width but in IE11, the function doesn't work. Can somebody please help.

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: Implementing bindings is not vanilla javascript.  Given the use of $scope, i am guessing this is either Angular 1 or 2?

Answer (score -1):

do you mean something like this?

html:

`<div onclick="function(params)">content...</div>`

js:

```
function name(params) {
    var e = document.getElementById("idHere");
    e.width = params;
}
```

Comment: I tried few things and figured that getWidth(heading) function is not able to calculate width when in "style " tag. So I changed it to ng-style.

Comment: But now after adding ng-style...text-overflow:ellipsis has stopped working.

Comment: <div style="white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; max-height:48px;"
                            data-ng-bind="$eval('row.' + heading.key) | formatter:heading.format" title="{{$eval('row.' + heading.key) | formatter:heading.format}}"
                            ng-style="width:{{getWidth(heading)}}px;"></div>

Comment: hmmm, I am not very well known with the angular.js libary, I wouldn't know why this problem occures